# overloaded constructor InnerClass inside a method

Tags: java, overloading, local, inner-classes, anonymous-inner-class

I'm reading the book "Thinking in Java" by Bruce Eckel. I came across this assertion in the inner class chapter, which says: "the only justification for using a local inner class instead of an anonymous inner class is if you need a named constructor and/or an overloaded constructor"

I don't now if i understood well but:
**Is this the way of overloading constructors of Inner(local classes) inside method?**

```
abstract class ForInner {
abstract String getName();
abstract void setName(String newName);
abstract int getNumber();
abstract void setNumber(int newNumber);
```

}
class Outer{

```
public ForInner getSomeInner(String name) {
    class LocalInner extends ForInner{
        private String myName;
        private int myNumber;
        public LocalInner(String myName) {
            this.myName = myName;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return myName;
        }
        public void setName(String newName) {
            myName = newName;
        }
        public int getNumber() {
            return myNumber;
        }
        public void setNumber(int newNumber) {
            myNumber = newNumber;
        }
    }
    return new LocalInner(name);
}
public ForInner getSomeInner(int number) {
    class LocalInner extends ForInner{
        private String myName;
        private int myNumber;
        public LocalInner(int myNumber) {
            this.myNumber = myNumber;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return myName;
        }
        public void setName(String newName) {
            myName = newName;
        }
        public int getNumber() {
            return myNumber;
        }
        public void setNumber(int newNumber) {
            myNumber = newNumber;
        }
    }
    return new LocalInner(number);
}
```

}

I'm not sure if the assertion referring to this. But might have a guess that is not the case because **How different it would be of using in this way**

```
abstract class ForInner {
abstract String getName();
abstract void setName(String newName);
abstract int getNumber();
abstract void setNumber(int newNumber);
```

}

```
lass Outer{
public ForInner inner (String name) {
    return new ForInner() {
        private String myName;
        private int myNumber;
        {
            myName = name;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return myName;
        }
        public void setName(String newName) {
            myName = newName;
        }
        public int getNumber() {
            return myNumber;
        }
        public void setNumber(int newNumber) {
            myNumber = newNumber;
        }
    };
}
public ForInner inner (int number) {
    return new ForInner() {
        private String myName;
        private int myNumber;
        {
            myNumber = number;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return myName;
        }
        public void setName(String newName) {
            myName = newName;
        }
        public int getNumber() {
            return myNumber;
        }
        public void setNumber(int newNumber) {
            myNumber = newNumber;
        }
    };
}
```

}
thank in advance?

Comment: Think that it can be paraphrased in this way. If you need to create more that one instance of inner class then use *local inner class instead of an anonymous inner class*.

Comment: Sorry. Are you sure about that? Because I think you can create more than one instance of anonymous inner class. When you refer instance are you referring to objects right?!

Comment: Yes I'm referring to objects. Will try to describe it in a answer.

Comment: I've checked the book and *Another reason to make a local inner class rather than an anonymous inner class is if you
need to make more than one object of that class.*, the same idea as in my first comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class OuterClass {
    Runnable printA = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Print A");
        }
    };
    Runnable printB = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("MESSAGE:" + " " + "Print B");
        }
    };

    class PrintMessage implements Runnable {
        private String msg;
        public PrintMessage(String msg) {
            this.msg = msg;
        }

        // overloaded constructor
        public PrintMessage(String prefix, String msg) {
            this.msg = prefix + " " + msg;
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
    }
    Runnable printC = new PrintMessage("Print C");
    Runnable printD = new PrintMessage("Print D");
    Runnable printE = new PrintMessage("MESSAGE:", "Print E");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OuterClass sample = new OuterClass();
        sample.printA.run();
        sample.printB.run();
        sample.printC.run();
        sample.printD.run();
        sample.printE.run();
    }
}
```

There are two instances of `Runnable` implemented as anonymous classes. While `printA` is created you cannot use it to create `printB`. You should create anonymous class from the beginning (i.e. override all abstract methods).

If an inner class created based on `Runnable`, you can use it in form `new PrintMessage()` to create new instances. Besides that it's possible to use non-default constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Ah ok so when have this code

```
class OuterClass {
    public Runnable printA() {
        return new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Print A");
            }
        };
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OuterClass outer = new OuterClass();
        Runnable printA = outer.printA();
        Runnable printB = outer.printA();   
    }
}
```

In this case I'm not creating multiply instances of a single anonymous inner class. Instead I'm creating multiple anonymous classes that use the same source code. Is that Rigth?!
Thanks

Comment: Feel free to upvote or accept my answer if it helped)

Comment: Ok but if in this case Im creating multiple anonymous classes attach to a single reference how different it is from the local one I can still use it in the same way i use a local Inner class. I can use method, edit variable as i do in the local class. At the end is not all the same?!

Comment: 1. If you assign ones to a single reference only the last instance is accessible. 2. It's all the same when you use instances. Difference is how they are created

Comment: Ok, ok something starts to make sense. Its is clear that in order to overload a constructors, even if I could simulate that behaviour using anonymous class, I have to duplicate code and overload the method that is used to create the anonymous class rather that overload a constructor. ok ok nice thank Maxim